# ActionMailer.Net caused Azure to fail to initialize

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles, actionmailer.net

I've got an MVC4 app that utilises [ActionMailer.Net](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home)

This web app is hosted in an Azure cloud service. Everything works fine when running in the Azure simulator on my local machine. As soon as I publish to Azure, my role fails to initialize.

If I look at the intellitrace errors for the instance I can see it attempting to load System.Web.MVC and failing on that. A little further investigation, it appears it might be trying to load the MVC 3 library and failing because it can't find that version.

Has anyone come across this issue and found a solution?

Comment: take a look if you set "Copy Local true" of System.Web.Mvc dll.

Comment: It's configured to copy already, the rest of the MVC site works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you redirecting the older MVC references to 4.0 in your web.config?

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: This is already configured in the web.config. Should it be different to allow ActionMailer to work?

Comment: It appears it's a complexity with Azure and assembly binding. More information was available here: https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/issue/40/mvc3-dependancy

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on the ActionMailer.Net forum on bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/issue/40/mvc3-dependancy